# Error in rename a module in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1?

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, rename, file-rename

Whenever I rename a module I make in Intellij IDEA, it always show the new name in [], next to the old one, rather than just renaming the module as a whole.[image]
How do I replace the name of the module? The iml seems to change but not the name in Intellij or a file explorer. Also, I renamed it by doing refactor-->rename, and then proceeded to restart the IDE. It still would not change. Thanks.

Comment: You've already changed the module name with `Right Click -> Refactor -> Rename...`, but now you just need to close Intellij, rename the folder, and reopen Intellij.

Comment: why are you using Intelli idea. You can use Eclipse. @Anshul Gupta

Comment: In my opinion, I feel Intellij is a lot better than Eclipse. I used to use Eclipse, which I thought had the same rename procedure as intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was rename the actual folder, then it would completely rename.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your module name to follow below steps.
1. Project Structure(press [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Shift] on Windows)
2. move to 'Project' tab
3. rename 'Project name'
4. move to 'Modules' tab
5. rename 'name'

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA has some guildlines to rename the directory which is maintained by git.
Please look into this link
[JetBrain Guidlines for rename directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.1/rename-dialog-for-a-directory.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_content=2019.1)

I tried to rename a directory but it is showing like cannot rename it seems
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Projects tool window right-click a directory or a module that you want to rename.
2. From the context menu, select Refactor | Rename (⇧F6).
3. In the dialog that opens, select what you want to rename. If you have a module with one content root, and it has the same name as your module, you can rename them both simultaneously.

[image: Select refactoring dialog]

4. In the dialog that opens, add the new name, check where to search for references and click OK.

See [Rename a directory or a module﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html#87e031db)

**NOTE:** that for Maven or Gradle based modules - you should configure module names in corresponding Maven/Gradle build files.

Comment: To rename, I right clicked on the module and did refactor-->rename, but there was only an option to change the name of the module. When doing this, it just shows the new name in brackets and does not replace the old one, like it does with classes.

Answer (score 0):

For me I have to remove all the modules manually and reload each module again after that name was showing properly.